# Objective C: Table View Scrolling only works when keyboard is open

Tags: objective-c, scroll, uitextfield, uitableview

I have two Textfields in my TableView. When one is selected for editing, the Textfield is moving to the center of the screen. This is what I do:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.nameTextField) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0  inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    }
    else if(textField == self.passwordTextField) {
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine, but only when the keyboard is open. If I click on a Textfield for the first time or if the keyboard was closed, no scrolling is happening.

Can anyone tell me why or do you have another solution?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try textFieldShouldReturn method, It will get called when keyboard goes down. Following logic works for me, Add this method to your code:

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
return YES;
```

}

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Suchit. But it isn´t changing anything. :-/ The TableView scrolls back to point zero when closing the keyboard, but the problem remains